# ASP.NET Core Model Binding from Route and Query String

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to perform a GET request such as https://localhost:12345/api/employees/1/calendar/2018/2019?checkHistoricalFlag=true

I have created this method in my controller which works as expected:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("/api/employees/{clockNumber:int}/calendar/{yearFrom:int}/{yearTo:int}")]
public IActionResult Get(int clockNumber, int yearFrom, int yearTo, bool checkHistoricalFlag = false)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

However I would prefer to use the following view model:

```
public class DetailsQuery
{
  [Required]
  public int? ClockNumber { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int? YearFrom { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int? YearTo { get; set; }
  public bool CheckHistoricalFlag { get; set; } = false;
}
```

This binds the route parameters but ignores "checkHistoricalFlag" from the query string:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("/api/employees/{clockNumber:int}/calendar/{yearFrom:int}/{yearTo:int}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]DetailsQuery query)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

Removing [FromRoute] results in a 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error.

Is it possible to bind both the route parameters and query string values to a single view model or do I need to specify the query string values separately?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("/api/employees/{clockNumber:int}/calendar/{yearFrom:int}/{yearTo:int}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]DetailsQuery query, bool checkHistoricalFlag = false)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Does `[FromUri]` attribute on `checkHistricalFlag` have no effect?

Answer (score 8):

The comment from Imantas pointed me to using [FromQuery] on the view model which now looks like:

```
public class DetailsQuery
{
  [Required]
  public int? ClockNumber { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int? YearFrom { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int? YearTo { get; set; }
  [FromQuery]
  public bool CheckHistoricalFlag { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The controller method is now:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("/api/employees/{clockNumber:int}/calendar/{yearFrom:int}/{yearTo:int}")]
public ActionResult Get([FromRoute]DetailsQuery query)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

Which works as expected.

Thanks for the pointer Imantas.